# Losing \n In String Through GET

Tags: php, get

When I pass a \n in a string to this code through a link, it is getting lost in the Home and Splash portion of the conditional but if I hard-code the $String value to include it, it works as it should

For example using **$String=$GETvalue;** when there is a \n in the $GETvalue, will show *Some text\nMore text* but if I use **$String="Some text\nMore text";** it shows:

```
Some text
More text
```

as it should. How can I maintain the \n through a GET?

```
<?php  
$FontPath = "/internals/truetype/";
$FontName = "vineritc.ttf";
$EnableShadow=TRUE;
$CenterAlign=TRUE;

$GETkey = key($_GET);
$GETvalue = current($_GET);

switch ($GETkey):
    case "AuthorID":
        $Year = date("Y");
        $AuthorName = DBLookup("SELECT `AuthorName` FROM authorbiographies WHERE `ID`=$GETvalue",$siteDB);
        $String = "Copyright &copy; $Year\n$AuthorName";
        $FontSize = 10;
        $Angle = 0;
    break;
    case "CategoryID":
        $String = DBLookup("SELECT `CategoryName` FROM categories WHERE `ID`=$GETvalue",$siteDB);
        $FontSize = 15;
        $Angle = 0;
    break;
    case "Home":
        $String = $GETvalue;
        $FontSize = 28;
        $Angle = 0;
    break;
    case "Splash":
        $String = $GETvalue;
        $FontSize = 38;
        $Angle = 0;
    break;
endswitch;

$TextImage = textimage();

header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: image/png');

echo $TextImage;
?>
```

This code is called with:

```
<img src="/viewers/show.php?Splash=Some+text\nMore+text!">
```

Comment: `\n` really disappears or is it there when you see source code on browser? Maybe you just need to use nl2br()

Comment: \n is there in the source code but it is disappearing (probably by being encoded) in the GET when it is sent. I completely rewrote the original question based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I was sending the string as (shortened here without alt or title:

```
<img src="/viewers/show.php?Splash=Some+text\nMore+text!">
```

when it should have been sent as:

```
<img src="/viewers/show.php?Splash=<?=urlencode("Some text\nMore text!");?>">
```

No decoding is apparently needed on the receiving end. Odd, I snapped awake in the middle of the night with the answer after fighting it for so long! It was sending it urlencoded() originally, then someone here in another area told me it was unnecessary so I removed the **urlencode()** from it, then forgot I had done so.